# IOS COCOAPOD with sources

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to update the CocoaPods in my Xcode project, but when I try to run `pod update`, it doesn't work.

My podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/MapQuest/podspecs-ios.git'
target 'FireBaseFixed' do
pod 'Firebase', '3.11.0'
pod 'MOCA'
pod 'MapQuestMaps'
end
```

And the response

```
daortiz:FireBaseFixed dortiz$ pod update 
Update all pods 
Updating local specs repositories 
Analyzing dependencies 
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Firebase (= 3.11.0)`

[!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Problem with ' symbol. Please remove those and add again

Comment: i fix it , but same problem

Comment: There is no specifications for Firebase version 3.11.0. Please check the version again and add. or else remove it to get latest version

Comment: When you are specifying specific version of pod, you have to use like this
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'

Comment: if , I remove firebase , show error in next line
[!] Unable to find a specification for `MOCA`

Comment: Check there is any pod with name MOCA

Comment: pod moca exist , I have projects with same pod and , works

Comment: It seems like there are many issues going on here. Fix the smart quotes and the non-existent 3.11.0 pod issue then update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you require Firebase 3.11.0 exactly?

To get the latest framework, use

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

Anyways, your problem is not the version, rather the sources, you seem to have omitted cocoapods main source and included only MapQuestMaps.

You also need to specify the version of MapQuestMaps as the are all pre-release versions and cocoapods will cry foul.

The code below fixes that.

```
source 'https://github.com/MapQuest/podspecs-ios.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'FireBaseFixed' do
    pod 'Firebase', '3.11.0'
    pod 'MOCA'
    pod 'MapQuestMaps', '3.4.1-1.1'
end
```

If the above doesn't work, sync your repo by running the following

```
pod repo update --verbose
```

Then run

```
pod install
```

Comment: yeah , firebase 3.12 have a bug , 13 sloved

Comment: Pod install , but when I compile project show me: "d: 10 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: @DanielORTIZ the compile error is a different issue, best to raise it as a new question. If my solution helped you, please mark it as the answer to help any future S/O users.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working version of your podfile

```
   # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/MapQuest/podspecs-ios.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'FireBaseFixed' do

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'MOCA'
pod 'MapQuestMaps’, '~>3.4.1-1.1'

end
```